# Performance difference / improvement with custom Linq extensions

Tags: c#, performance, linq

First of all, I'm not sure if this question fits to this community. If it doesn't please tell me where to move it :)

So, I've caught myself writing Linq expressions like this very often:

```
var xy = someSource.Where(x => x.Property == value).Select(x => new Y(x));
```

When refactoring my code I thought this actually enumerates my source twice, so I wrote this little extension (nothing too special actually):

```
    public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectWhere<TIn, TResult>(this IEnumerable<TIn> source,
        Func<TIn, bool> predicate, Func<TIn, TResult> selector)
    {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
            if (predicate(item))
            {
                yield return selector(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

So I can replace my query with

```
var xy = someSource.SelectWhere(x => x.Property == value, x => new Y(x));
```

Of course, this will only have a noticeable performance improvement (if it does at all), if the source enumerable is large or each "move next" takes long..

My question is: Does this really improve performance (a little) and is it worth having this extension?

Comment: "I thought this actually enumerates my source twice" - why would you think so?

Comment: I think so, because `Where` and `Select` both need to enumerate themselves to perform their actions, dont't they?

Comment: @Stefan: no, both `Where` and `Select` are *lazy*, they have no need in enumerating.

Comment: I don't think it improves performance but it does make the code easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: Well, you can create a benchmark and [check it by yourself](https://dotnetfiddle.net/r33jde)

Comment: @Fabjan wow, it's even worse.. good to know. Might be a bad idea to improve Microsofts methods ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ and enumerables are by design lazy, that means that they only iterate the source collection when you actually request the items from the result collection.

So getting one element from your `xy` will only fetch items from the original `someSource` until it hits one that matches your `Where` expression, which is then passed directly to the `Select` transformator. It really only evaluates one item at a time. You have to imagine a pipeline here:

Requesting an item from `xy` iterable makes the `xy` iterator request an item from the `Select` iterable which makes that iterator request an item from the `Where` iterable which iterator will request items from the original iterable—one item at a time.

This makes enumerables very lazy (which is often very good for performance) but also adds a little overhead to manage those various iterators in the chain: The longer the chain (the more operations you have), the more impact will that overhead have.

In general, there is little to no reason to optimize these operations. LINQ is fast enough to not become a bottleneck quickly, and unless you actually identified it as a bottleneck in your application (by profiling your code), you shouldn’t invest effort to optimize your code. This is especially true for LINQ since LINQ aims to be very readable and easy to follow.

Of course, you could make additional extensions for combinations of common LINQ operations, but I’d say that you very likely won’t notice the performance gain that removing one iterator from it would give you.

If you’re really writing performance critical stuff, and you know that your LINQ expressions are a bottleneck, but you want to continue being able to write LINQ expressions for readability reasons, you could take a look at [roslyn-linq-rewrite](https://github.com/antiufo/roslyn-linq-rewrite). It is a Roslyn-based tool that rewrites your LINQ expressions at compile time into procedural code, making them super efficient without sacrificing the ease LINQ expressions give you.

Comment: Nice explanation :)
To be honest I didn't dive into the Linq mechanisms that much yet.. I just like to use it.
Well, this makes my extensions pretty useless

Answer (score 1):

The Linq `Where` and `Select` are being processed in one enumeration.

This results in one enumeration:

`var xy = someSource.Where(x => x.Property == value).Select(x => new Y(x));`

**So nothing to optimize here.**